# How to use the penultimate position of an iterator in c++

Tags: c++, boost, iterator

I have the following piece of code which helps me to write a bunch of values into a comma separated file format. My problem is, that I do not want a comma after the last element written to `normcsv`. How can I use `beg` in an If clause of the kind:

```
if(beg == penultimate element)
then.... bla bla...
```

Everything I tried out ended up with the iterator being mad invalid

```
ReadLine.erase(0,17);
int offsets[] = {8,8,8,8,8,8};
boost::offset_separator f(offsets, offsets+6);
boost::tokenizer<boost::offset_separator> RVBEARline(ReadLine,f);
boost::tokenizer<boost::offset_separator>::iterator beg;

for( beg=RVBEARline.begin(); beg!=RVBEARline.end();++beg )
{                                   
    copy=*beg;
    boost::trim(copy);
    if(copy.compare(0,1,".")==0)
    {
        copy.insert(0,"0");
    }

    normcsv << copy <<",";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of printing the comma *after* the element except during the *last* iteration, print it *before* the element except during the *first* iteration. For that, you can use `if(beg != RVBEARline.begin())`.

Comment: +1, except for I would avoid both calls to `.begin()` and calls to `.end()` (in condition) with each loop iteration.

Comment: @Lumpi : Track your state with a simple `bool` variable instead of repeated comparisons to `.begin()`.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to ruakh's "first plus rest" approach, you can do with one less local variable by using a loop-and-a-half construct:

```
{
  auto it = x.begin(), end = x.end();

  if (it != end)
  {
    for ( ; ; )
    {
      process(*it);

      if (++it == end) break;

      print_delimiter();
    }
  }
}
```

Here `x.begin()` and `x.end()` are only called once. There is one mandatory comparison per loop round, the minimum possible. The check for emptiness is hoisted outside.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just always remove the last character since you know it will be an extraneous comma?

Comment: Well, in the penultimate line of my snippet i send "copy" to the outfile, followed by a comma (which I have to insert io to get a csv format). That's fine and needed for all but the last "copy" being sent to the file.